# Why the AWS load balancer not able to make my website secure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have configured the AWS load balancer to secure my website, i.e. to resolve through "https". But when I use`(https://www.schoolnskill.com)`, it gives

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable.
```

So I have followed the below steps to configure my environment.

1. I created a domain name in route53 and have been issued with a SSL/TLS certificate through AWS Certificate manager.
2. For my load balancer I set up listener for https:443 and attached the above certificate with it.
3. The security group for my ec2 instances allow http and https requests (although I believe the load balancer ec2 target will communicate using http).

I have attached a screenshot with the summary of the configuration.

[image]

Then in the `ROUTE 53`, I edited the `'A' record` of `'www.schoolnskill.com'`. Below are the changes I made.

```
Alias:- yes
Alias target:- chosen the application LB
Routing policy:- simple
```

Then save the settings.

I can see that whenever I type `'http://www.schoolnskill.com'`, it is redirected as `'https://www.schoolnskill.com'`

Health_CHK
[image]

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: How does the health of the targets look?

Comment: added a screenshot to the original post. Please check

Comment: What are target group settings?

Comment: How to find that? please suggest.

Comment: Ok, I found the target group settings. Please ask specific question so that I can answer accordingly. There are too many information

Comment: I have seen the 'target' tab inside target group --> load balancer_name. It says that the load balancer is in availability zone that is not enabled for the load balancer. Would that be the probable cause?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the availability zones. The AZ of my load balancer was different from that of EC2 instance. I matched the AZ of ALB to my EC2, and it worked.

Thank you,